# JSON payload to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, ssjs

I have a form and want to add the submission values to a data extension. This is what the payload looks like:

```
{
    "emailType": "Business",
     "title": "Founder",
     "firstName": "Walter",
    
}
```

I have tried the following code but my `ParseJSON` function is returning undefined. Is there something I'm missing here?

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
  
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
var jsonpost = Platform.Request.GetPostData()
var jsonparse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(jsonpost);

var emailtype = jsonparse.emailtype

Write("jsonpost: "+jsonpost);
Write("<br>jsonparse: " +jsonparse);
Write("<br>emailtype: " +emailtype);
```

This is what I receive:

```
jsonpost: "{\r\n    \"emailType\": \"Business\",\r\n     \"title\": \"Founder\",\r\n     \"firstName\": \"Walter\",\r\n    \r\n}"

jsonparse: undefined
emailtype: undefined
```

Comment: If you hard-code the JSONpost data in your page, does it parse correctly?  Looks like a source form-data encoding issue to me.

Comment: 2 things,  First - for your `var emailtype = jsonparse.emailtype` it should be `var emailtype = jsonparse.emailType` (SSJS is case sensitive).     SECOND - when writing your jsonparse, you should wrap it in a Stringify() `Write("<br>jsonparse: " + Stringify(jsonparse));` Doing those changes, produced the right output for me.

Answer (score 5):

So I did a test on a landing page in SFMC using your code and noticed 2 things:

1. For your `var emailtype = jsonparse.emailtype` it should be `var emailtype = jsonparse.emailType` (SSJS is case sensitive).
2. When writing your `jsonparse`, you should wrap it in a `Stringify()` `Write("<br>jsonparse: " + Stringify(jsonparse));`

Doing those changes produced the right output for me. I tried it both via a POST to the page from POSTman and by hard coding your example request json from above in the page.

FROM POSTman:

```
jsonpost: {
"emailType": "Business",
"title": "Founder",
"firstName": "Walter",

}<br>jsonparse: {"emailType":"Business","title":"Founder","firstName":"Walter"}<br>emailtype: Business
```

From hardcoded in page:

```
jsonpost: { "emailType": "Business", "title": "Founder", "firstName": "Walter", }
jsonparse: {"emailType":"Business","title":"Founder","firstName":"Walter"}
emailtype: Business
```

The JSON you provided is not proper syntax either with that added comma at the end of 'firstName', but it seems that the ParseJSON is smart enough to account for that and properly adjust.